# Loading non RGBA 4-tile multi page tiff images with skimage into dask array

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, dask, scikit-image

I need to read a folder full of multi-page tiffs generated by the Suite2p neurobiology package.
From the Suite2p source code the multi-tiffs are created as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from tifffile import TiffWriter

# fake example images
img_5_tiles = np.random.randint(0,65535,(5,10,20), dtype='uint16')
img_4_tiles = img_5_tiles[1:,...]

# save fake images
with TiffWriter(r'D:\5tiles.tiff') as tif:
    for frame in img_5_tiles:
        tif.save(frame)

with TiffWriter(r'D:\4tiles.tiff') as tif:
    for frame in img_4_tiles:
        tif.save(frame)
```

When I try to read them into dask, skimage.io default tifffile plugin fails to get the correct shape:

```
from dask.array.image import imread
from skimage import io

def read_with_tifffile(path):
    return io.imread(path, plugin='tifffile')

# should produce (5,10,20) instead of (1,10,20)
imread(r'D:\5tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_tifffile).shape
```

I can overcome this by using the non-default skimage.io.imread plugin 'pil'

```
def read_with_pil(path):
    return io.imread(path, plugin='pil', mode='L')

# gives (1,5,10,20) which is acceptable
imread(r'D:\5tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_pil).shape
```

Unfortunately, if the number of tiles equals to 4, skimage starts to handle the shape differently:

```
# gives (1,10,20,4) instead of (1,4,10,20)
imread(r'D:\4tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_pil).shape
```

From reading skimage docs, it's probably trying to interpret my image as RGBA and then fails.
Is there a solution to force 'uint16' multipage read for all image shapes?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Disable writing metadata when saving each frame: `tif.save(..., metadata=None)`

Comment: Unfortunately, solving it from the  'save side' is not a valid option for now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: But, `img_4_tiles` / `img_5_tiles[4:,...]` _has_ the shape `(1, 10, 20)` ... why should it produce `(5, 10, 20)`?

Comment: You are absolutely right. Sorry, my bad. I have corrected `img_5_tiles[4:,...]` to `img_5_tiles[1:,...]`. The question is why
`imread(r'D:\5tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_pil).shape` gives (1, 5, 10, 20) while `imread(r'D:\4tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_pil).shape` gives (1, 10, 20, 4).

Comment: Try `tifffile.imread(..., is_shaped=False)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [cgohlke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453463/cgohlke)'s comment:

```
from dask.array.image import imread
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import tifffile

# fake data
img_with_4_tiles = np.random.randint(0,65535,(4,10,20), dtype='uint16')

with tifffile.TiffWriter(r'D:\4tiles.tiff') as tif:
    for frame in img_with_4_tiles:
        tif.save(frame)
        
# my original bad solution
def read_with_pil(path):
    return io.imread(path, plugin='pil', mode='L')

print(imread(r'D:\4tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_pil).shape)

# a good solution from the horse's mouth (https://pypi.org/user/cgohlke/)
def read_with_tifffile(path):
    return tifffile.imread(path, is_shaped=False)

print(imread(r'D:\4tiles.tiff', imread=read_with_tifffile).shape)
```